# Coolbits "1" does nothing (GTX 560ti, 310.14, Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, xorg, overclocking

I can't find a way to enable overclocking on Ubuntu 12.04.

This is my `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "nvidia"
    VendorName "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Option "Coolbits" "1"
EndSection
```

The only levels of Coolbits that I have tested were 1, 4 and 5, only 4 worked.

What else can I do to enable Coolbits 1?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `Coolbits` to overclock Fermi based boards (such as the gtx560), it is not supported by the hardware. Your only alternative is to flash a custom firmware with a tool called nvflash (not available on canonical servers).

Even though a linux version of nvflash is available it is suggested to boot from a DOS box and use the dos version of the same tool. You can find a very exhaustive guide [here](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=158620) **BUT flashing a custom firmware is a very dangerous business** (you may end up with a bricked video card) and I would discourage you from taking that route.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I wanted coolbits to underclock actually, on GTX 560ti the clock is around 950 and that causes crashes.

Isn't there a tool like Zotac Firestorm on Ubuntu? Or a way to emulate it? Looks like Zotac only developed a version for windows.

Comment: I'm afraid your only option is to flash a customized firmware